# How can I change a primary key value in one-one relationship?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Hi
I'm using entity framework 4 as business layer.
I've two table in one-one relationship:
Users <---> Employees
Employees table have the same primary key as Users table, so when I add record to Users i have to add one to Employees with the same PK value...and that throws an exception.
Actually I'm doing this using entity framework :

```
// after adding new Users entity, I add new Employee item to it  
newUserEntity.Employee = newEmployeeEntity;
```

What should I do to be able to insert the PK manually ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exception do you get? How are keys in your tables defined?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to fix this.

The first one is why do you have two tables. Could you instead have a single table but have a User and an Employee view of that table.

The second is that if you have two tables, why do both of them have an auto generated primary key. You could generate the key in the program (or get it from a key table) and then just insert the key values in the tables.

Comment: I've two table because the Employee entity should has the same properties as User entity in addition to other properties related to Employee..  
I should say that I have another table called Clients which has the same relationship as Employee with Users...that why i should make three tables : Users,Employees and Clients.  
Thanks

Comment: Not 3 tables, one table and 2 views

Comment: I knew that view is a virtual table you can build using fields of other tables,if that it do you mean that I should put all the fields in Users tables (even those for Employee and Client tables), and when I insert new record for employee I leave the fields of client NULL and vise versa? I want to do what i want using the way you mentioned (the second one) but for some reason i can't do it.